# CameraCaptureTask of Windows Phone 8 App is not working in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows Phone 8 App, which is Live on Windows Store. Now, recently I got a complaint from one of my Client that they are not able to capture Photo, only selection of Photo works from Gallery. This issue is appearing when they updated their device to Windows 10. I am using following code

```
private void CapturePhoto()
    {
        CameraCaptureTask cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraCapture.Completed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //checking if everything went fine when capturing a photo
            if (args.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
                return;
            args.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
            string evidenceName = Path.Combine(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER_PATH, "evidence_" + MCSExtensions.GetDateTimestamp() + ".jpeg");
            saveAndDisplayEvidence(args.ChosenPhoto, evidenceName);
        };
        cameraCapture.Show();
    }
```

I am already developing Windows 10 App as an update but till I update the app. I need to solve this issue so they can use it for capturing images.

Can someone suggest, how to solve this issue?

Comment: So, where is it not working? Can you point out the line of code where you get an error?

Comment: @MarcelTheis I don't get any error , when we capture photo we get two options by default in Camera App i.e `Refresh` and `Accept`. For me `Accept` comes as disabled for Windows Phone 8 app

Comment: Ok, now I got it, your using the camera app provided. I had the same problem and wrote a camera capture myself.

Comment: In my new Windows 10 App, it works fine as Windows 10 API is different. But old Windows Phone 8 Camera API doesn't work properly.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to cover both in one app, you´ll have to write it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

The UI on Windows 10 is "less than intuitive", and to take a picture using the CameraCaptureTask, the end user needs to use the `...` in the app bar, and `Choose location` to select camera. For your scenario, you may wantt o upgrade to a Windows 10 UWP app and use [`CameraCaptureUI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my application as well.
You have to create your own camera capturing application
You can go through the following links

1. [Advanced Camera Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662940(v=vs.105).aspx)
2. [Basic Camera Application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359).