# Accept of image not possible when using CameraCaptureTask

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

On certain devices (Only some models), the accept of an image, taken with camera is no longer possible.
On two different phones, but with the same Windows 10 build, it works on one, but not the other.
When the app switches to the camera, the picture can be taken, but not accepted. The accept icon is disabled, and only the retake option is available.

The app is built for Windows Phone 8 with SilverLight.

The code:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;

cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);

cameraCaptureTask.Show();

void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
    }
}
```

On certain phone-models (MS 640 and 650) the cameraCaptureTask_Completed is never fired, since the accept button is disabled.

My guess is that it is a bug in the latest Windows 10 release, affecting some phones. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CameraCaptureTask of Windows Phone 8 App is not working in Windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347658/cameracapturetask-of-windows-phone-8-app-is-not-working-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away with the next update of Windows Phone.
It was a bug on certain Windows 10 builds.